# Constructor function treated as "is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have two variables (technically "constants" here, they are defined in this order) :

```
const variable1 = function(someParam){//constructor function
    if(arguments.callee.caller === this.constructor.prototype.variable2ID){
        if(/*some stuff*/){
            /*some setup using the this keyword*/
        }else
            return this.constructor.prototype.variable2ID(document).ready(someParam);
    }else{
        return Object.create(null);
    }
}
```

and

```
const variable2 = function(someParam){
    return new this.createVariable1(someParam);
}
```

variable1 has a bit of setup for inheritance and its constructor:

```
variable1.prototype = Object.create( Array.prototype );
variable1.prototype.constructor = variable1;
```

Later on, I define some properties (again, in this order):

```
Object.defineProperty(variable1.prototype, "variable2ID", {
    value: variable2,
    __proto__: variable2.prototype,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
});
```

and

```
Object.defineProperty(variable2, "createVariable1", {
    value: variable1,
    __proto__: variable1.prototype,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
});
```

My problem is the following:

When I call `variable2("*")` it throws an error : `TypeError: this.createVariable1 is not a constructor`.
I don't understand why this error is thrown since the function stored in `variable2.createVariable1` is `variable1` which is a constructor function.
It is even weirder that, when I explicitly call `new variable2.createVariable1("*")` it does what's intended (ie calls `variable1` and returns `Object.create(null)` since not called from `variable2`).

My question is this :
Can you help me figure out what I have done wrong while attempting to create an object within the function with the `this` keyword ? (and how to achieve the call to the constructor (`variable1`) within `variable2`)

Many thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: you've added `createVariable1` to `variable2` rather than `variable2.prototype` - which is why `this` does not have `createVariable1`

Comment: @JaromandaX: This is a Q&A, not a chatroom; if you know the answer, please write it in answer form in the answer section. Comments are for requesting clarification and berating people. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I understand how this place works, I haven not added that as an answer as I don't think it's the only problem in the code - lol @ berating people, by the way :p - I'm just checking some other possible problem with the code in the mean time, if that's OK with you :p

Comment: Adding `createVariable1` to `variable2.prototype` instead of `variable2` didn't have any impact on the call to `variable2`

Comment: "*`arguments.callee.caller === this.constructor.prototype.variable2ID`*" - WAT?

Comment: Don't use `__proto__` in object literals. Especially not in property descriptors where it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Bergi This bit of code check if the constructor function has been called by the said function (ie not just by `new /* ... */`). I'll follow your advice regarding `__proto__` thx :D.

Comment: @Vivick Yeah, but `arguments.callee` is deprecated (use `variable1` instead), `.caller` is deprecated (without replacement), `this.constructor.prototype` probably is meant to mean `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`, and accessing `.variable2` as a property of anything is not necessary when it's already in scope: just use `if (variable1.caller === variable2)`! Or rather, **don't do that**. In general, never let what a function does depend on where it is called from. Why did you think you needed that? Just write different functions and call the appropriate one.

Comment: Edited my answer to comply with some of the deprecations. Just restricting access to the object creation function to its associated function (for different instances of the "hub" part mainly).

Comment: @Vivick You should restrict the access by scoping rules, not by questionable `if` conditions inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some debugging and a bit of test on a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnmghre4/) to figure out whether or not I should attach the property to `variable2.prototype` or `variable2` I stumbled across this and smashed my head against my desk for not noticing it earlier:

In my function :

```
const variable2 = function(someParam){
    return new this.createVariable1(someParam);
}
```

The `this` keyword (when calling `variable2(/*params*/)`) is bound to `window` (since that's the default behavior, as a call to `console.log` is really a call to `window.console.log`).

Therefore, I just replaced `this`by `arguments.callee` like so :

```
const variable2 = functon(someParam){
  return new arguments.callee.createVariable1(someParam);
}
```

This also solved the property definition "issue". In order to work with `arguments.callee`, the definition is the following :

`Object.defineProperty(variable2, "createVariable1", {`

If you define it on the prototype, `arguments.callee.createVariable1` is undefined.

Huge thanks to those who tried to help me out on this :D !

**EDIT**
To comply with deprecation, here's an updated version (if it is even remotely necessary) :

```
const variable2 = function f(someParam){
    return new f.createVariable1(someParam);
}
```

And

```
const variable1 = function obj(someParam){//constructor function
    if(obj.caller === this.constructor.prototype.variable2ID){
        if(/*some stuff*/){
            /*some setup using the this keyword*/
        }else
            return this.constructor.prototype.variable2ID(document).ready(someParam);
    }else{
        return Object.create(null);
    }
}
//I'll be fine with the long ass get the prototype thing,
//it's only used in this specific part of the code (which is about 1/200th of it)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue that I see is that `this` inside

```
return new this.createVariable1(someParam);
```

isn't referring to the `variable2` object but rather the window, because `variable2` isn't part of any parent object other than window. If you `console.log(this)` inside the function it will show you this.
If you're trying to make a generator function you could change your code to this:

```
function variable2(someParam){
    this.create = function () {
        return new this.createVariable1(someParam);
    }
}
```

and the generator as follows:

```
var creator = new variable2("*");
console.log(creator.create());
```

Comment: + solution doesn't have all the benefits of "abstracting" the object creation (chaining without additional parentheses / no confusion in chaining / getting object without explicit `new`)